# Inequality indexing using optimization variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, syntax

Let the variables `A` and `B` be `n x 1` doubles and `c` be a scalar. My goal is to sum the values in `A` corresponding to indices for which the optimization variable `x` is greater than `B`. I have written this up below:

```
x = optimvar('x',n); % Creates optimization variable 
objfun = sum(x); % Creates objective function
constraint = sum(A(x>=B))>=c; % Constraint based on logical indexing
```

The third line in the code above returns an error message because optimization variables are not compatible with inequality indexing. Specifically, `x>=B` cannot be input as indexes into `A`.  Is there a way around this? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Thank you!

Comment: In optimization models, we typically use binary decision variables to model this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use function handles for both, the objective function as well as the constraint-function:

```matlab
objfun = @(var) sum(var); 
constraint = @(var) sum(A(var>=B)) >= c;
```

In fact, for the objective function `objfun`, you may also use `objfun = @sum`. This is a *function handle*. You can think of it as a pointer or reference to a certain function. Function, which work with one input can be used directly (with `@`). The optimizer calls the function and uses the optimization variable as input.

Now, if you have multiple inputs, you need to create a function, where you define all inputs but one. For this, you create an *anonymous function handle*, where you tell the handle what variables are placed where: `@(var) sum(A(var>=B)) >= c`. The variable `var` is the changing input and the other variables `A`, `B`, and `c` are taken from the workspace at the point of definition (i.e. the function handle is unaffected if you change the variables later or even delete them).